# How can you make a menu with different choices?

Tags: bash, scripting

Problem is that i want something similar to this but instead it will take you numbers, like for an example:

1) Choice1 
2) Choice2 
3) Choice3 
4) Exit

Anyone can help with this, or can make it easier for me please that would be much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, where do you want numbers instead?

Comment: Like the options instead be numbers and a simpler way to write the code

Comment: I ran your program and it prompted with numbers already. If I answer '2' then $REPLY is 2 and $opt is "Option 2". It seems that it already does what you want - but I've probably misunderstood. Perhaps show exactly the output you want.

Comment: So what do you need more?